# Don't count the null value in array.lenght

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem I want to get the length of my model but is always equal to 2.

If I display my `modelFriend.lenght` I have this: `[Thu Jul 06 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200,null]`

and `null` is consider like a value so the `length` is equal to 2.

How can be count real size that is `modelFriend.lenght = 1` if I choose one date and `modelFriend.lenght = 2` if I choose 2 date

This is my code:

```js
public selectDate = (date) => {
  if (this.mode === 'period') {
    const dates = this._modelFriend ? [this._modelFriend[0], this._modelFriend[1]] : [null, null]

    if (!dates[0] || dates[1]) {
      dates[0] = date
      dates[1] = null
    } else {
      dates[1] = date
    }
    this._modelFriend = dates
    if (this._modelFriend.length === 2 ) {

      this.model = dates

    }
```

Comment: So wouldn't it be right to avoid the `null` values at first? The current approach seems a bit wrong to me.

Comment: ok what is your solution because it for validation test 
if the user enter just one date is wrong so that ng-invalid but if he selected a period that is ng-valid 

so for that I want to test if my array length is egal to 2 

How would you proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function below, which uses [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), to count the non-null elements from the array:

```js
function countNonEmpty(array) {
  return array.filter(Boolean).length;
}

var array = [new Date(), null];
console.log(countNonEmpty(array));
```

Comment: thanks to reply but how can be use this in my code I don't now how can be implemented that 
sorry I'm beginner ...

Comment: You can just replace the `this._modelFriend.length === 2` to `countNonEmpty(this._modelFriend) === 2`

Comment: Or, if you don't want to create that function (countNonEmpty), you can use this directly: `this._modelFriend.filter(Boolean).length === 2`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the array always has the length of 2 in your case. That is why I simply would check if `this._modelFriend[0]!=null && this._modelFriend[1]!=null`, instead of doing filtering and check the length of the new filtered array. If the expression evaluates to `true` you got 2 dates.

Everything else is complicated, more difficult to read and an overhead.

Comment: the result is same if I evaluate this._modelFriend.filter(Boolean).length === 2 

or if I evaluate this._modelFriend[0]!=null && this._modelFriend[1]!=null

the result is true or false ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same.
The approach with the filter makes sense, if the questioned array would by dynamic in length. As it always will  have the length of 2, it is definitely an overhead.